# What is cloudfront.net AdWare?

Tags: malware, virus

Here is some information I research about cloudfront.net AdWare:

I've seen several topics talk abou this malware: [Cloudfront.net Malware](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_other-protect_scanning-windows_10/cloudfrontnet-malware/ed88deb3-492e-4f89-a819-182df5257478)

According to this article: [How to remove CloudFront.net adware (Virus Help Guide)](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/cloudfront-net-virus-removal/)

> Cloudfront.net is a legitimate and safe content delivery network owned by Amazon, however cyber criminals are abusing this CDN to deliver malicious content.

And

> This CloudFront.net redirect is usually caused by adware installed on
>   your computer. These adware programs are bundled with other free
>   software that you download off of the Internet. Unfortunately, some
>   free downloads do not adequately disclose that other software will
>   also be installed and you may find that you have installed adware
>   without your knowledge.

---

So here is what exactly happen:

I just click a link on the internet and my Kaspersky pop up notification, said it's `not-a-virus:HEUR:AdWare.Script.Generic` (so the adware come from the link, **not** because I install any adware programs which are bundled with other free software)

So I just click the link (not install any exe file), here is the links Kaspersky claims to be adware, don't go to these link below

```
http://d1dqwj4dc78lwy.cloudfront.net/?jwqdd=634223
http://d10lumateci472.cloudfront.net/TbnJtZU9RBgQBclhBWVd9XQ%3D%3D
```

Is there any chance my PC has been infected? I mean if the Windows' administrator permission right doesn't pop up, then the cyber criminal can't harm me right? Is it just a false positive from Kaspersky?

So what exactly cloudfront.net adware and how can it infected me? Does it mean every `cloudfront.net` is detected as adware?

Comment: I'd say it's very unlikely that you're infected, unless you start getting these popups randomly on sites that should be safe. It's way more likely that the adware Kaspersky warned about was part of the website you were visiting.

Answer (score 2):

> I mean if the Windows' administrator permission right doesn't pop up, then the cyber criminal can't harm me right?

There are no administrator permissions needed to install extensions into your browser, change the start page or generally run and programs as your user which then also can read, modify or delete any kind of data owned by the user. For example ransomware does not need administrator permissions to encrypt the data of the non-privileged user.

> Is there any chance my PC has been infected?

This is not clear from the information you provide. It might be that you've tried to visit a site which incorporates lots like ads in a way similar to how adware does it. It might also be that these scripts serving ads were injected by some adware locally on your system. If the problem happened only with this specific site it is more likely that it is a problem or feature of the site you visited, if it happens with lots of other sites it is probably a problem local to your system.

> So what exactly cloudfront.net adware

Adware, as the name says. That is it might place ads into pages you visit, replace existing ads, maybe clicks on ads in the background so that it looks like that a user is interacting was the ads (i.e. ad fraud).

> ... and how can it infected me?

You've already cited the typical infection vector:

> These adware programs are bundled with other free software that you download off of the Internet.

Comment: He said he clicked a link and got the following warning, that doesn't mean that he's infected. You'd get the same warning too if you click the link

Comment: @FINDarkside: the question is about confusing but I interpret it this way that the browser detected links which should not belong there, which suggests for me that these were included by the Adware.

Comment: Might be, but I interpreted it other way. To me it just seems that OP is confused and thinks cloudfront is adware. If you skip all the quotes at the start, it just sounds like he clicked a link, Kaspersky said it blocked adware and now he's wondering if he's infected.

Comment: @FINDarkside: What  made me lean to my conclusion are the samples provided by the OP. These are all Javascript files which are unlikely to be included as a clickable link because this would not execute the Javascript. Instead they were probably included as link into the current page and maybe the AV showed these URL as the problems so that they ended up in the OP's question. But again, the question is confusing.

Comment: He did say that "I just click a link on the internet" though, it's entirely possible that the site he went was requesting those files, nothing in his post really suggests that they were injected by some malware on his computer. But we yeah, need clarification from OP.

Comment: Thank you, @FINDarkside understand me correctly, I just click a link and Kaspersky pop the warning Adware, so I wonder how dangerous is this Adware, Is there any chance it infect me. The quote at the beginning just to show the effort I research.

Comment: @123iamking: it is not fully clear from your question what exactly happens. But given that Kaspersky claims that some script included in the site you visited is from adware I suspect that you've actually have this adware on your system already from some previous actions, like installing some seemingly unrelated software or browser plugins.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: firstly, sorry for unclear question and thanks for your effort for the question. But Kaspersky only pop up the warning when I click that link, since then everything works ok, I've experienced no adware on my browser so far, so I think it's just the link fault. I'm just curious what that kind of damage that link could give.

Comment: @123iamking: it is unclear for me where the links come from you've included in your question since these are not links to click on but script loaded by HTML pages. Apart from that the damage from adware is just more ads. But the ability to inject arbitrary content into the sites you visit could be misused much more, for example to read passwords. But this would not be called adware anymore then.

Comment: He clicked a link and the site requested those scripts, seems pretty obvious for me. The links are the one Kaspersky is telling it blocked, I assume.

Comment: @FINDarkside: which means that the site either had this links originally included (site attacked, strange site or false positive) or that some adware installed on your system has injected these links into the site, i.e. modified data during transit or inside your browser. I don't know which of these is the case.

Comment: Given his description it's way more likely that it's just malicious site. There's really no reason to believe other way, I think you're just getting confused by his quotes about cloudfront malware. If he got these on multiple sites I'm pretty sure he would have told.

Comment: @FINDarkside: you might be right. I've changed the answer to reflect that it is not clear and what is more likely.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront is the CDN service of Amazon Web Services (Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_CloudFront)). You can create an AWS account and use it, but obviously also people who do malicious things can use it.

But unless there is a really bad security breach in your browser, there is no way your computer was infected just by visiting this website.

I think that your virus scanner alerted because that subdomain may be known as a virus server or something like that.